# How do I set a crontab every 40 minutes?

Tags: cron

I try set crontab every 40 minutes with

```
*/40 * * * *
```

but this way is every 40 minutes and next is of 20 minutos, and repeat.

Comment: The working is fine. The cronjob is running after 40 minutes of previous cronjob. If you want cronjob to run on 40th minute then, I think, `*/40 * * * *` should be `40 * * * *`.

Comment: For the crontab to run every 40 minutes, this ```*/40 * * * *``` run every hour o'clock and hour and 40.

Comment: Here is a crontab generator. Try this. https://crontab-generator.org/

Comment: ↑And one more https://crontab.guru

Answer (score 2):

You can't set it on this way. You should explicitly describe the hours:

```
0,40 */2 * * * 
20 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23 * * *
```

This above will work on all Linux distributions. But on some UNIX OS you will need to replace `*/2` with `0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22`